# How to pass the same request or catch response to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Is it possible to catch response from DataTables when reloading the table or is it possible to pass all the data (I mean filters) which is passed by the DataTables request with own function?

I need SQL query built by the SSP class and then use it in my own function. I want to do something with filtered data, but I need much more data than is in my table.

I thought about something like this:

```
var myData = table.ajax("myFileWithModifiedSSP.php").load();
```

In this case it would pass all params like to refresh the table, but in the end it would return something else and NOT refresh the dataTable.

My second thought is to send only parameters with ajax to my file and do what I need. Something like this:

```
function myFuncton(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "myURL.php",
    data : DATATABLES_PARAMETERS,
    success : function(data){
       //do what I need
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

I didn't mention it earlier that I have initialized table, added some own filters. Everything works perfect now.
The only thing I need is to get somehow all request parameters which are send by the Datatables script and use them for something else.

For example let's say that I have button named "export", I filter data in my table using my filters and search engine (from DataTables), then I get result into my table.
The next step is to click "export" and now I need previously passed arguments (by DataTables) to use them in other script to do something with the data. I only need the same parameters, to build new query and do something with data.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - do you basically want to pass additional data back from the server?

Comment: No, I need to resend parameters with my own function, to regenerate the same query, which was generated by SSP Class, to fill table with (filtered) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ajax.params()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29), that gets the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

See this example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: "data.json",
    serverSide: true
});

table.on('xhr', function () {
    var data = table.ajax.params();
    alert('Search term was: ' + data.search.value);
});
```

If you use data returned by `ajax.params()` as value to `data` property of `$.ajax()`, you can get the same request that could be submitted to a different URL, for example:

```
$.ajax({
   'url': 'script.php',
   'data': $('#example').DataTable().ajax.params()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this

```
$('#datatable_id').dataTable( {
"iDisplayLength": 50,
"ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
    $.get(url, {
        param1: param1_value,
        param2: param2_value,
    }, function(res) {
        callback({ 
            data: response.data
        });
    });
}});
```

Please note I am using get as ajax method type. You can use post or what ever you would like to.

Comment: I think it's not the way. I have everything done, initialized table (in var), own filters, dataTable filters. The only thing I need is the query made with SSP (where condition) to filter data and than use it for other proposes.

Comment: @Alex then please create a snippet so that we can help you in a better way